# Is there a way to check for conflicts in requirements.txt prior to pip install?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a long list of dependencies for my project. `pip install -r requirements.txt` in an empty (virtual) environment takes several minutes. I wanted to update several packages and I'm now stuck a cycle of pip aborting the install because of conflicts and me resolving them. Isn't there a way where I can check for conflicts before installing a hundred packages?

Comment: In case there are already things installed in your virtual environment, you could try `pip check`, maybe it will show things that can be fixed before installing the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @sinoroc unfortunately no, I'm building a docker container that runs pip install on creation.

Comment: How was the `requirements.txt` file generated? -- Maybe you should also focus on speeding up the installation in the container. For example, you could mount *pip*'s download and build cache directories as volumes; or make sure that nothing gets built from source distribution but gets directly installed from wheels instead.

Comment: @sinoroc I think you're right. Seems like there's a lot I could still improve. Thank you!

Comment: You need to get as fast as possible to the point where pip fails to find a solution so that you can fix `requirements.txt` and restart.

Comment: You might also want to give [_`pipgrip`_](https://pypi.org/project/pipgrip/) a try.